# FieldLevelValidationForm - How to make it configurable

Tags: redux-form

I am running into this situation:

I want to apply multiple validations on a field which like example below:

```
<Field name="username" type="text"
    component={renderField} label="Username"
    validate={[ required, maxLength15 ]}
 />
```

But I want to make the 15 as a configure number instead.

For example, userNameValidatiorConfig = [required, {maxLength: 15}]

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

The validate prop of Field contains usual javascript functions. Thus you could do something like

```
validate={(value) => maxLength(15)(value)}
```

That is if your validation functions look like

```
const maxLength = (max) => (value) => value && value.length > max ? "Bad input!" : undefined;
```

Comment: I think you can even shorten this to `validate={maxLength(15)}`, since that already returns a validation function.

Comment: Haha fair enough :)